# supervisor restart causes zombie uwsgi process

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

I have a python/Django project (myproject) running on nginx and uwsgi.

I am running uwsgi command via supervisord. This works perfectly, but on restarting supervisord it creates zombie process. what am i doing wrong? What am I overlooking to do this cleanly? any Advise?

Often times supervisor service takes too long. at that point I have found the following in `supervisor.log` file

> INFO waiting for stage2_BB_wsgi, stage3_BB_wsgi, stage4_BB_wsgi to die

**Point to Note:** I am running multiple staging server in one machine, namely stage2 .. stageN

> **supervisor.conf** file extract
>   
>       `[program:stage2_BB_wsgi]
>       command=uwsgi --close-on-exec -s /home/black/stage2/shared_locks/uwsgi_bb.sock --touch-reload=/home/black/stage2/shared_locks/reload_uwsgi --listen 10 --chdir /home/black/stage2/myproject/app/ --pp .. -w app.wsgi -C666 -H /home/black/stage2/myproject/venv/
>       user=black
>       numprocs=1
>       stdout_logfile=/home/black/stage2/logs/%(program_name)s.log
>       stderr_logfile=/home/black/stage2/logs/%(program_name)s.log
>       autostart=true
>       autorestart=true
>       startsecs=10
>       exitcodes=1
>       stopwaitsecs=600
>       killasgroup=true
>       priority=1000`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set your `stopsignal` to `INT` or `QUIT`.

By default `supervisord` sends out a `SIGTERM` when restarting a program. This will not kill `uwsgi`, only reload it and its workers.